# Cakephp alternative to not show logedin users, login/register page./

Tags: cakephp-2.3

I understand that if you don't want to show users such as logging, registration pages, all you have to do is ..

```
if ($this->Session->check('Auth.User')){
    $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'index'));
}
```

inside a controller/action ex: Users/login. But, I have many pages that I don't want logged in users to see, so it becomes cumbersome to use the above code everywhere. Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The code you show is the *wrong way* of checking for authorization. It will fail for stateless authorization and it will fail if in just a single place a typo happens or the auth session is named different. You're basically ignoring the features the framework provides for this use case.

The proper way would be to use the authorization adapters of the framework. I recommend you to [do the auth tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html).

What you described sounds like you have different roles, like "not logged in user", "logged in user" and some other role like "admin" that is allowed to see pages that "logged in user" is not allowed to see.

Either use a plugin like [SimpleRbac](https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-simple-rbac) or [implement your own role based authorization adapter](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#creating-custom-authorize-objects).

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have different roles for admins and users. But I am using cake2.x which I started using recently, so I am not very expert in this

Comment: You should **always** tag your questions with the version you're using.  Cake2 has also a documentation http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/index.html look the needed information up.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your `AppController`

```
public function beforeFilter() {
     if ($this->Session->check('Auth.User')){
          if($this->params["controller"] == "YourController" && $this->params["action"] == "YourAction"){
              $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'index'));
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: That would mean, I have to add all the controllers and actions? This is simpler, but I was hoping for the opposite method like `$this->forbid('login', 'register', 'forgot_password', 'activate_account')` ...